# Is it good to use id of object from a third-party server as my PK at SQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I write some app which analyze Instagram and Twitter posts (post serves in separate tables) and I load comments and likes too. So, it's good to use they id's as my primary key, or is better to create my id's which will not be related to third-party id.

Comment: I'm a fan of having my own primary keys, although this can go too far.  If you don't have that much data, 4-byte integers will probably be more efficient than more complex keys.

Comment: can you guarantee that their ID columns are indeed unique and will remain unique? If the answer is yes then you can. If not then you should create a surrogate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own ids in your database. In general you want these properties to be true about your primary keys:

1. Unique. This one the database management system will enforce for you.
2. Unrelated to the data they identify. This means that you shouldn't be able to calculate the primary key to any row based on the info in the row. For example, first name+last name would be a bad primary key for a People table, and credit card number would be a bad primary key for BillingInfo table.

By using the id generated by a third party service as your PK, you are unnecessarily coupling your database with their service.

Instead, there is a common pattern of using an altId column to store an extra id. You could even name the column better by calling it twitterId or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from *uniqueness* and *minimality* three sensible criteria for deciding on keys are *stability*, *simplicity* and *familiarity*.

Above all, there is the business requirement: the need to represent the external reality with some acceptable degree of accuracy. If your database is intended to represent accurately things sourced from some given domain then you will need an identifier also sourced from that domain.